# Password Prompt not showing for sudo command in Capistrano3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, nginx, centos, capistrano3

I am running `cap production deploy:setup_config`

I get the following output:

```
DEBUG[659d52b0] Running /usr/bin/env [ ! -d /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2 ] on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DEBUG[659d52b0] Command: [ ! -d /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2 ]
DEBUG[659d52b0] Finished in 2.413 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG[2ea020b0] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default ] on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DEBUG[2ea020b0] Command: [ -f /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default ]
DEBUG[2ea020b0] Finished in 0.507 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
No default Nginx Virtualhost to remove
INFO[e0a045fc] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DEBUG[e0a045fc] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=/home/deployer/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config )
INFO[e0a045fc] Finished in 0.405 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUGUploading /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/nginx.conf 0.0%
INFOUploading /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/nginx.conf 100.0%
INFOcopying: #<StringIO:0x007fad45824cc8> to: /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/nginx.conf
DEBUGUploading /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/database.example.yml 0.0%
INFOUploading /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/database.example.yml 100.0%
INFOcopying: #<StringIO:0x007fad448839e0> to: /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/database.example.yml
DEBUGUploading /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/log_rotation 0.0%
INFOUploading /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/log_rotation 100.0%
INFOcopying: #<StringIO:0x007fad4413b2f0> to: /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/log_rotation
DEBUGUploading /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/monit 0.0%
INFOUploading /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/monit 100.0%
INFOcopying: #<StringIO:0x007fad46816898> to: /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/monit
DEBUGUploading /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/unicorn.rb 0.0%
INFOUploading /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/unicorn.rb 100.0%
INFOcopying: #<StringIO:0x007fad46ab7a20> to: /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/unicorn.rb
DEBUGUploading /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/unicorn_init.sh 0.0%
INFOUploading /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/unicorn_init.sh 100.0%
INFOcopying: #<StringIO:0x007fad46a4f7e0> to: /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/unicorn_init.sh
INFO[a1c87854] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/unicorn_init.sh on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DEBUG[a1c87854] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=/home/deployer/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 /usr/bin/env chmod +x /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/unicorn_init.sh )
INFO[a1c87854] Finished in 0.483 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[30551413] Running /usr/bin/env whoami && echo ${PATH} on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DEBUG[30551413] Command: whoami && echo ${PATH}
INFO[30551413] Finished in 0.552 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG[30551413]     deployer
DEBUG[30551413]     /home/deployer/.rbenv/shims:/home/deployer/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/deployer/bin
INFO[30551413] Finished in 0.552 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[60b61747] Running /usr/bin/env sudo ln -nfs /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DEBUG[60b61747] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=/home/deployer/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 /usr/bin/env sudo ln -nfs /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ )
DEBUG[60b61747]     [sudo] password for deployer:
```

Now when i enter a password. its showing the password and also it doesn't even work.
The Task is as Following: `lib/capistano/tasks/setup_config.cap`

```
namespace :deploy do
    task :setup_config do
        on roles(:app) do
        # make the config dir
        execute :mkdir, "-p #{shared_path}/config"
        full_app_name = fetch(:full_app_name)

        # config files to be uploaded to shared/config, see the
        # definition of smart_template for details of operation.
        # Essentially looks for #{filename}.erb in deploy/#{full_app_name}/
        # and if it isn't there, falls back to deploy/#{shared}. Generally
        # everything should be in deploy/shared with params which differ
        # set in the stage files
        config_files = fetch(:config_files)
        config_files.each do |file|
            smart_template file
        end

        # which of the above files should be marked as executable
        executable_files = fetch(:executable_config_files)
        executable_files.each do |file|
            execute :chmod, "+x #{shared_path}/config/#{file}"
        end

        # symlink stuff which should be... symlinked
        symlinks = fetch(:symlinks)

        symlinks.each do |symlink|
            execute "whoami && echo ${PATH}"
            sudo "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/#{symlink[:source]} # sub_strings(symlink[:link])}"
        end
    end
end
end
```

In deploy.rb I have the following regarding ssh:

```
set :pty, true
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true, :keys => %w(/home/SMD/.ssh/id_rsa)}
set :use_sudo, false
set :default_shell, '/bin/bash --login'
```

I can't figure out what the problem is.
Also i'm concerned for the failed code also. ==>

```
DEBUG[659d52b0] Command: [ ! -d /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2 ]
DEBUG[659d52b0] Finished in 2.413 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any solution without setting the `deployer` a passwordless sudoer.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding something like this to your deploy.rb file(or the corresponding deploy environment file)

```
set :password, ask('Server password', nil)
server 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx', user: 'root', port: 22, password: fetch(:password), roles: %w{web app db}, primary: true
```